# Property 'width' does not exist on type 'GlobalEventHandlers'

Tags: javascript, typescript, image

I would get the size of an image, following this tutorial, but I get a TypeScript error:

```js
const img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
```

[How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

> Property 'width' does not exist on type 'GlobalEventHandlers'.

What to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The load handler's `this` isn't typed to the image. Reference the image directly instead.

```
const img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  console.log(img.width + 'x' + img.height);
}
```

Or use `addEventListener`.

```
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
})
```